# Controlling whitespace in EJS

Tags: express, ejs

I have a conditinal to check if a users is not signed in then a class is added to a td element. 
The EJS looks like this:

```
        <td class="<%_ if (!currentUser) { _%>
                notSigned"
            <%_   } _%>">
```

Rendered HTML:

```
                <td class="                        notSigned"
">
                    Monitor the database 
                    <div class="ui accordion">
```

There is all the leading whiespace on the class and the bracket closes on the next line. I'm new to EJS, what's the best way to control whitespace?

Comment: How about using a ternary operator like `currentUser? '': 'notSigned'` in one line?

Comment: Yes that works, I'm actually doing that in many templates, so does writing the if statement in one line like so:
  `<td class="<%_ if (!currentUser) { _%>notSigned<%_   } _%>">`

I was hoping that there is some way to control whitespace for multi-line ejs, since it's easier to read.

Comment: It doesn't quite solve it but `app.set('view options', {rmWhitespace: true});` will trim out a lot of the space. I think that's intended to be more like a minification process though, so it doesn't necessarily make it easier to read the generated HTML.

Answer (score 0):

My EJS experience is pretty limited but I did have one idea that I thought was interesting enough to share.

If you add functions to the application locals they be accessible within the template:

```
app.locals.$if = function(condition, output) {
    return condition ? output : '';
};

app.locals.$unless = function(condition, output) {
    return condition ? '' : output;
};
```

The names `$if` and `$unless` are arbitrary but hopefully they're good enough to demonstrate the idea.

You could then write something like this in your view:

```
<td class="<%=
    $unless(currentUser, 'notSigned')
%>">
```

I don't know whether you find that easier to read than the alternatives you've already mentioned but I think it reads quite well.

Answer (score 0):

simply use this to make white spaces visible

Example:

```
Arriving Date: <%- moment(arriving_date).format('Do MMMM') %> <%- arriving_time %>
```